# Need to send large attachment file using Microsoft Graph API in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, microsoft-graph-api

I am using a code from the below link. code is very helpful for EWS developer to migrate using Graph API. I got everything in place except one thing. I am not able to send large attachment > 4 MB in an email. so I went through Microsoft Graph Docs and came to know that we have to use createUploadSession and then upload via LargeFileUploadTask. So I am not sure how to implement this code in below repository.

https://github.com/ivfranji/GraphManagedApi

Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If the file size is between 3 MB and 150 MB, create an upload session, and iteratively use PUT to upload ranges of bytes of the file until you have uploaded the entire file. A header in the final successful PUT response includes a URL with the attachment ID.

**Sample:**

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var attachmentItem = new AttachmentItem
{
    AttachmentType = AttachmentType.File,
    Name = "flower",
    Size = {fileSizeInBytes}
};

await graphClient.Me.Messages["{message-id}"].Attachments
    .CreateUploadSession(attachmentItem)
    .Request()
    .PutAsync();
```

See the doc for more info - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-large-attachments?tabs=csharp#step-1-create-an-upload-session

Comment: Thanks @vicky, but can you see the code I have posted and can it be done using the same concept. basically that code is not using graphServiceClient. It is a wrapper which uses HTTP request to Microsoft graph api.

Comment: Sorry , i haven't saw the code , you provided the repo link, could you please provide the exact code that you tried .